# How to make a navigation button inside a view with a image and title inside the view React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

If someone touches the view, there have to be opened a different page. But in this view there is also a image and text. So I have searched for it on the internet, but I couldn't find a good solution.

I have tried to place a button in the view, but it doesn't work.

```js
    export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.containerbetween}>
              <View style={[styles.box, styles.box1]}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../assets/images/Pooplog.png')}
                />
                  <Text style={styles.white}>Poep log</Text>

              </View>
              <View style={[styles.box, styles.box2]}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../assets/images/Agenda.png')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.white}>Kalender</Text></View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.containerbetween}>
              <View style={[styles.box, styles.box3]}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../assets/images/Analyse.png')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.white}>Analyse</Text></View>
              <View style={[styles.box, styles.box4]}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../assets/images/Tips.png')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.white}>Tips en weetjes</Text></View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {//navigate here}} style={[styles.box, styles.box1]}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../assets/images/Pooplog.png')}
                />
                  <Text style={styles.white}>Poep log</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
```